# Oracle partition exchange generating unique constraint violation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, database-partitioning

I have a process that does the following:

1 - create table load_table1 as select * from table1 where partition_number = P1

 2 - --- insert new records into load_table1 ---

 3 - apply indexes and constraints to load_table1 (all are global and match what table1 has)

 4 - alter table table1 exchange partition P1 
 with table load_table1 including indexes without validation

Both load_table1 and table1 have a unique constraint set. It does not fail when applied to data in load_table1, but when doing the partition exchange I get a unique constraint violated error on the constraint in table1. I'm not sure how this is happening because I'm doing a complete swap of the partition and the partition_number field is part of the unique key - so if the unique key is fine in load_table1 and that same data is going into table1 why is the unique failing (I also verified that all records are getting loaded in their proper partition, so there are no records where partition_number = P1 that are in a different partition than P1)?

I've verified as well that the index for the constraint as well as the constraint are applied locally on table1 and globally on load_table1.

Comment: Might help to see the full DDL definition for both tables as they exist right before you attempt the exchange, plus the actual text of the error message.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm curious as to what might have been causing the issue.